# Netbeans warning on Event injection

Tags: netbeans, warnings, observer-pattern, cdi

I use CDI Observer pattern in my LanguageOfSystem bean.

```
@Named(value = "languageOfSystem")
@SessionScoped
public class LanguageOfSystem implements Serializable {

   @Inject private JsfUtils eeJsfUtils;
   @Inject private Event<LangEvent> langEvent;
   private LangEvent docLangEvent = new LangEvent();
```

where LangEvent is simply:

```
package jav;

import java.util.Locale;

public class LangEvent {
   private Locale locale;

   public Locale getLocale() {
      return locale;
   }

   public void setLocale(Locale locale) {
      this.locale = locale;
   }
}
```

Everything works fine, but NetBeans gives me a warning:
[image]

```
Unstatisfied dependency: no bean matches the injection point.
```

Should I check or change something?

Answer (score 8):

No worries, the code is fine. It looks like [this](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=201825#c6) NetBeans bug.

BTW,

```
@Named(value = "languageOfSystem")
public class LanguageOfSystem
```

is already default and can be written as:

```
@Named
public class LanguageOfSystem
```